# Search for a word in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to search for the existence of the word `hi`.

```
import re
word = 'hi?'

cleanString = re.sub('\W+',' ', word)
print(cleanString.lower())

GREETING_INPUTS = ("hello", 'hi', 'hii', "hey")
if cleanString.lower() in GREETING_INPUTS:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

When `word = 'hi'`, it prints `yes`. But for `word = 'hi?'`, it prints `no`. Why is it so and please suggest any solution.

Comment: Because `'hi '` isn't in that tuple of values.

Comment: @ThomasKühn no; the problem is the value not how they're testing it against the list.

Comment: ```answer = 'yes' if word in GREETING_INPUTS else 'no'```

Comment: Call `str.strip` on your cleanString: `cleanString = re.sub('\W+',' ', word).strip()`. This removes whitespace around the string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a lot.

Comment: @L3viathan thanks. I needed this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
cleanString = re.sub('\W+',' ', word)
```

With:

```
cleanString = re.sub('\W+','', word)
```

Because you're replacing all the matches of `'\W+'` with `' '`, a space, so the string would be `'hi '`, so then you need to replace it with empty string `''` for it to work, the string would become `'hi'`